# What is the expected behaviour Cancelling async request in Redux-observable using takeUntil

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

i am new to RXJS, i found Redux-observable canceling async request using takeUntil is very useful. but while i was testing it i found that the actual request is still going on even though we cancel the request..

i have this JSbin code snippet to test.

https://jsbin.com/hujosafocu/1/edit?html,js,output

here the actual request is not canceling, even if you cancel the request by clicking the cancel (multiple times) button.

i am not sure this is how it should be.. if yes, then what does it meant by canceling async request. I am bit confused.. Please share some thoughts..

any respond to this will greatly appreciate.. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is very subtle, but obviously important. Given your code:

```js
const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER)
    .delay(2000) // <-- while we're waiting, there is nothing to cancel!
    .mergeMap(action =>
      Observable.fromPromise(
        jQuery.getJSON('//api.github.com/users/redux-observable', data => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        })
      )
      .map(fetchUserFulfilled)
      .takeUntil(action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_CANCELLED))
    );
```

The kicker is the `.delay(2000)`. What this is saying is, "don't emit the action to the rest of the chain until after 2000ms". Because your `.takeUntil(action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_CANCELLED))` cancellation logic is inside the `mergeMap`'s projection function, it is not yet listening for `FETCH_USER_CANCELLED` because there is nothing to cancel yet!

If you *really* want to introduce an arbitrary delay before you make the ajax call, but cancel both the delay OR the pending ajax (if it reaches there) you can use `Observable.timer()`

```js
const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      Observable.timer(2000)
        .mergeMap(() =>
          Observable.fromPromise(
            jQuery.getJSON('//api.github.com/users/redux-observable', data => {
              alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            })
          )
          .map(fetchUserFulfilled)
        )
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_CANCELLED))
    );
```

I imagine you don't *really* want to introduce the arbitrary delay before your ajax calls in real-world apps, in which case this problem won't exist and the [example in the docs](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/Cancellation.html) is a good starting reference.

---

Another thing to note is that even without the delay or timer, cancelling the ajax request from your code doesn't cancel the *real* underlying XMLHttpRequest--it just ignores the response. This is because Promises are not cancellable.

Instead, I would highly recommend using RxJS's `AjaxObservable`, which *is* cancellable:

```js
Observable.ajax.getJSON('//api.github.com/users/redux-observable')
```

This can be imported in several ways. If you're already importing all of RxJS a la `import 'rxjs';`, it's available as expected. Otherwise, there are several other ways:

```js
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax';

ajax.getJSON('/path/to/thing');

// or

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/dom/ajax';

Observable.ajax.getJSON('/path/to/thing');
```

It's important to remember, like all the Observable factories, `Observable.ajax` is **lazy** meaning it does not make the AJAX request until someone subscribes to it! Where as `jQuery.getJSON` makes it right away.

So you can put it together like this:

```js
const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      Observable.timer(2000)
        .mergeMap(() =>
          Observable.ajax.getJSON('//api.github.com/users/redux-observable')
            .do(data => alert(JSON.stringify(data)))
            .map(fetchUserFulfilled)
        )
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_CANCELLED))
    );
```

A working demo of this can be found here: https://jsbin.com/podoke/edit?js,output

Comment: Wow, awesome this is very well explained and all my queries are now cleared.. Thanks alot for making this efforts.. 

i have tested it and works perfectly.. Again the idea of using AjaxObservable is pretty amazing i tested that also causing some console errors but definitely go forward with this ...

Comment: One more good thing i have noticed.. the cancel option is killing all (related) request, this will be very helpful if a user (accidentally) requested same call multiple time.. regards

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone in future..

Like jayphelps mentioned above the better solution is using RXjs AjaxObservable, because it is canceling the actual XMLHttpRequest rather than neglecting the responds.

But currently there is some issues going on RxJS v5 "RxJS Observable.ajax cross domain issue"

good solution i found is "allows bypassing default configurations" 
like below:

```
     const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
              action$.ofType(FETCH_USER)
                .mergeMap(action =>
                  Observable.timer(2000)
                    .mergeMap(() =>
                        Observable.ajax({
                            url:`//api.github.com/users/redux-observable`,
                            crossDomain: true
                        })
                        .do(data => alert(JSON.stringify(data)))
                        .map(fetchUserFulfilled)
                    )
                    .takeUntil(action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_CANCELLED))
                );
```

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1732

Comment: The issue you linked to was fixed [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/1758) and included in our releases since 5.0.0-beta.10. If you still believe there is a bug, could you create a new ticket with a way to reproduce?