# What is the scenario where a Ajax/Promise should be cancelled?

Tags: ajax, promise, cancellation

I have used [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) calls before, and [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). I thought that the advantage with promises is the simplified programming model and there are no callbacks. I have not seen a scenario where a ajax or promise call bas to be called.

What is the scenario where a Ajax / Promise call should be cancelled? Once an ajax or promise is called to return some data from the server though some API (twitter API for example) via `XMLHttpRequest`, why that call has to be cancelled?

Comment: afaik there is no clean way to cancel a promise

Comment: I updated the question with more clarification.

Comment: After Ajax response we can cancelled using deferred/promise approach. But directly can not cancelled Ajax call.

Comment: @NileshKhisadiya Do you know the reason why an ajax call has to be cancelled? Is it a scenario where the user wants to cancel retrieving the data from a server API?

Comment: @wonderfulworld there's mostly no need to cancel an ajax. or in other words, you probably cannot. Once it is sent to server, you can just send more requests, not cancel the previous one unless obviously carefully implemented. your question would make a lot more sense if you ask about websockets instead of ajax/promises, but again, i'm just curious to know why do you want a hypothetical situation without any obvious reasons?

Comment: I have read enough that an ajax call can be cancelled but promise can't be. I see that the [abort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort) is to cancel a request. I'm trying to understand where in the app a situation of cancellation raises?

Comment: A promise is not "called". It's a result value. What you can cancel is a pending operation, which will lead to the promise being rejected.

Comment: @wonderfulworld In general, you cancel an operation from doing further calculations/processing when you don't need its results any more. Examples are when the user closes a dialog or navigates away. The prime example is a autocomplete with ajax, where the request to fetch results is cancelled as soon as the next letter is entered.

Comment: *"the advantage with promises is .... there are no callbacks"*: ehhhm... you might need to look again.

Comment: There is a case mentioned in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757112/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-cancelling-async-request-in-redux-observable-usin/40778640#40778640) answer.